# How to clearListener if that addEventListener exists?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can i remove listener but first to check if that listener exists?

```
       var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(markerR, 'click', function 

        (m) {
         if(exist) 
google.maps.event.clearListeners(listener1);

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to check if an EventListenner exists in js. All though you can make a variabel and save to this everytime you add an EventListener.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to like

```
if(element.hasOwnProperty('onclick'))...
```